# Can't calculate the old and new values difference in Firebase cloud trigger function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This cloud function scans new entries in one collection and adjusts data in the other.

Information from my `orders` collection is being sent to `cars` collection with their matching reference fields. However, the issue appears on the second function that updates data, when adjusting shipping costs it reduces `totalSales` with the number it is updated with, rather than the difference between them, meaning that shippingCost is substracting more than it should be.

I have tried to implement `change.before.data` but without any success.

The code itself is :

```
  exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
        .document('orders/{docId}')
        .onCreate((change, context) => 
        {
            var tasks = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                admin.firestore().collectionGroup('cars').where("carRef","==",change.data().sku).get().then(documents => {
                    docID = '';
                    documents.forEach((doc) => {                  
                        docID = doc.id;
                        totalSales = 0;
                        orderPrice = 0;
                        shippingCost = 0;
                        if(typeof doc.data().totalSales != "undefined")
                            totalSales = parseFloat(doc.data().totalSales);                        
                        if(typeof change.data().orderPrice != "undefined")
                            orderPrice = parseFloat(change.data().orderPrice);                        
                        if(typeof change.data().shippingCost != "undefined")
                            shippingCost = parseFloat(change.data().shippingCost);
                        newTotalSales = totalSales-shippingCost;
                        admin.firestore().collection('cars').doc(docID).update({"totalSales":newTotalSales}).then(documents => {
                            resolve();
                        });
                    });
                    if(docID=='') resolve();
                });
            });
            return tasks;                       
       }
    );
```

The issue is that the `totalSales` subtract shipping costs as instructed in the code, but  some orders may have further shipping cost adjustments, creating an issue of new value being deducted in addition to previous one. In this case, I would like to either deduct or add `shippingCost` difference to `totalSales` field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **onWrite** Event **instead of onCreate** event on your orders collecion which would give you access to `change.before.data();` and `change.after.data();`.

- `change.before.data();` would help you to access previous value instead of new value being subtracted.

Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_for_all_changes_to_a_document) if you need more info.